# Critical notes - lemma with multiple variants

Tags: footnotes, reledmac, reledpar

Running LuaLaTeX, I'm typesetting a critical edition. I need to input multiple variants for a lemma, within the same note, with a separator between each variant.

I could only manage to repeat the lemma with the new variant as a separate note:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertineotf}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\usepackage[noend, nopenalties, nofamiliar, noeledsec, series={A,B}]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\Xarrangement{paragraph}
\Xparafootsep{ $\parallel$ }
\firstlinenum*{1}
\linenumincrement*{1}

\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
The quick \edtext{brown}{\Afootnote{red A}\Afootnote{black B}} fox jumped.
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

I am trying to achieve this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add inside the same footnote. Remember: reledmac is neutral concerning the content of the footnote, all is your choice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertineotf}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\usepackage[noend, nopenalties, nofamiliar, noeledsec, series={A,B}]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\Xarrangement{paragraph}
\Xparafootsep{ $\parallel$ }
\newcommand{\sepinlemma}{$\bullet$}
\firstlinenum*{1}
\linenumincrement*{1}

\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
The quick \edtext{brown}{\Afootnote{red A \sepinlemma\ black B}} fox jumped.
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```